# MySql - create views with multiple definers

Tags: mysql, view, sql-grant

It's possible?

How?

I didn't find anything useful googling at, just this unanswered question:

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?100,215785,215785

Just to clarify, i have to reach this view from an user with different hosts, because at work we have a load balancer on more IPs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible, each view register a global name space, and you not able to override it same view name

however, you can use `user@%` which grant access for the user from all hosts

syntax can be found [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html)